# MS Access - Login

Tags: ms-access, authentication

When a user has logged in i would like it so that their user name is displayed in a Label in the main menu. here is my code.this at the minute allows the login form to check details entered and compares them to the  employees table to allow access to the Home form.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Private Sub ButtonLogin_Click()
Dim rs As Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Employees", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)

rs.FindFirst "UserName='" & Me.TxtUsername & "'"

If rs.NoMatch Then
    Me.LblWronguser.Visible = True
    Me.TxtUsername.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

Me.LblWronguser.Visible = False

If rs!Password <> Nz(Me.Txtpassword, "") Then
    Me.LblWrongpass.Visible = True
    Me.Txtpassword.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

Me.LblWrongpass.Visible = False

TempVars("EmployeeType") = rs!EmployeeType_ID.Value


DoCmd.OpenForm "Home"
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name


End Sub
```

after this stage i am stuck as to what the code for the "home" form to display the user that has just logged in (label) this would be the Unbound field seen.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming table structure is similar to below and the label is actually textbox you can use a `Dlookup` function.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDgIj.png    this shows the layout of my employees table, when i use the nz control source that you have provided, it come up with "error" in text box

Comment: Try this `=Nz(DlookUp("Username","Employees","EmployeeType_ID=" & TempVars("EmployeeType")),"")`

Comment: I now get an "Open Form" run time error. as the login is a separate form (where the code comes from) then when the login is inserted it then takes us to the Home page where the username should show

Comment: I believe the screenshot provided is of Home Page. This code won't give any error unless there is syntax issue. If the TempVars has the employee id set it will correctly show the username. You can try executing this code in immediate window using `?Nz(DlookUp("Username","Employees","EmployeeType_ID=" & TempVars("EmployeeType")),"")`

Comment: Run-time error '3464' datatype mismatch in criteria expression

Comment: Is `TempVars("EmployeeType")` number or string?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176540/discussion-between-matt-h-and-santosh).

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario, I am going to assume your textbox is called `Welcome`. You'll probably need to use  something like this:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Employees", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)

rs.FindFirst "UserName='" & Me.TxtUsername & "'"

If rs.NoMatch Then
    Me.LblWronguser.Visible = True
    Me.TxtUsername.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
Else 
    Me.Welcome = rs!UserName
End If

Me.LblWronguser.Visible = False

If rs!Password <> Nz(Me.Txtpassword, "") Then
    Me.LblWrongpass.Visible = True
    Me.Txtpassword.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

Me.LblWrongpass.Visible = False

TempVars("EmployeeType") = rs!EmployeeType_ID.Value

DoCmd.OpenForm "Home"
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
```

Note, this would only apply the username to the `Welcome` textbox. If a name was required, you would need to reference such a column differently, such as `Me.Welcome = rs!FirstName` or something. Also, since there is a password verification, you *probably* want to restructure things so that the name would only populate *after* the password portion has been passed properly.

Comment: The Me.welcome does not link to my page. as this code is from the login form which then directs to the Home form where the Welcome text box is. by adding the me.welcome it is not allowing for the text box to be found